# jQuery and PHP email form not running success function

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Hi there I'm trying to create a simple enough php email form without any need for page refreshing using the jQuery .ajax() method, however I want all the fields to reset once the email has been sent and at the moment this isn't happening for some reason!

Here's my jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
    url:"http://www.mysite.co.uk/contactMe.php",
    data: {'email': email,'content': content},
    success: function(response){
        $("#mailContent").css({ 'box-shadow': ''}); 
            $("#email").css({'box-shadow': ''});    
            $("#email").val('');
            $("#mailContent").val('');
            alert("DONE");

        return false;
        }
})
```

and here's my php

```
<?php 

function spamcheck($field)
  {
  //filter_var() sanitizes the e-mail
  //address using FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL
  $field=filter_var($field, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);

  //filter_var() validates the e-mail
  //address using FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL
  if(filter_var($field, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
    {
    return TRUE;
    }
  else
    {
    return FALSE;
    }
  }

$email = $_GET['email'];
$content = $_GET['content'];

$mailcheck = spamcheck($email);
  if ($mailcheck==FALSE)
    {

    }
  else
    {//send email
    mail("myemail@googlemail.com", "Subject: Website Contact Form",
    $content, "From: $email" );
    }

?>
```

Please note I've changed the url address and the email address for privacy, the email is sending fine as I receive it in my inbox. I've also tried the same thing using:

`.ajax().done(function{})` and there's no luck with that either, The worst thing is this works fine on another website I've used it on when I use .ajax() to create a commenting system, but it refuses to work at all on this site!!! :/

Your's frustratedly, Simon.

EDIT: Form:

```
    <form name="contact"> Email: <input name="email" type="text" id="email" ><br>
Message:<br> <textarea name="message" rows="20" cols="246" id="mailContent"></textarea><br> 
<input class="button" value=""> </form>
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, what browser do you use?  If you use Firefox, you should install Firebug and learn how to use the Network and Console tabs to debug AJAX requests and responses (F12).  If you use Chrome, developer tools has the same functions (also F12) built in.  It'll make your life a lot less frustrating.

Comment: is your site running on `localhost`? Or a real domain name?

Comment: If `success` isn't running that means the request isn't being completed, whether it be a 404 or a 500 (or whatever else). If you aren't familiar with JS debugging can you give us a link to your demo?

Comment: @Snuffleupagus - Incorrect.  There are many cases where a completed request may result in no "success" execution.

Comment: I do use firefox, I have firebug installed... I don't get anything showing under console ---> response... The GET is coloured red, but I get a 200 ok next to it. And yes Jakub I'm on a real domain name, I am aware ajax won't work on localhost :P

Comment: Could be a cross-domain issue, can't you just use `url:"/contactMe.php"` or is the script on a different server?

Comment: And yes @Snuffleupagus TheSmose is correct, the request does complete, as I receive the email in my inbox, but the success function doesn't run

Comment: @jeroen scripts are on same server, So I'll try what you said...

Comment: @jeroen OOOH OOOOOOH OOOOOOOOH that worked! Thank you very much! care to explain why that makes a difference? I guess it would help my learning to understand :)

Comment: If it solved your problem, I might as well put it in as an answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use ajax to `POST` cross-domain (read up on [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) for specifics); for security reasons the browser blocks that as it might take you (and your data) to shady sites without you noticing it.

If the script you are posting is on the same server, you should remove the domain name and use a path relative to the root of the web-site:

```
url:"/contactMe.php"
```

Comment: thank you very much :) nice explanation too :) have a cookie!